# Angular2- Editable Grid with formControlName

Tags: angular, primeng

We have a requirement to have editable grid, we have decided to use primeng datatable.

We are using the below code to achieve this, however it is not working as expected. I think problem is with formControlName, but I am not sure what is the issue.

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="lstchecklistModel" [responsive]="true" [editable]="true" [style]="{'margin-top':'50px'}">                    
                <p-column field="labelName" header="Checklist"></p-column>                    
                <p-column field="required" header="Required" [editable]="true" [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}">
                    <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                        <p-dropdown formControlName="required" dataKey="label" [options]="RequiredValues" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" required="true"></p-dropdown>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-column>
                <p-column field="required" header="Mail Received Date"></p-column>
                <p-column field="received" header="Recived?"></p-column>
                <p-column field="receivedDate" header="Mail Received Date"></p-column>
                <p-column field="mailReceivedDate" header="Mail Received Date"></p-column>
                <p-column field="updatedBy" header="Updated By"></p-column>
            </p-dataTable>
```

Thanks,
Pani

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to achieve this with below changes.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="lstchecklistModel" [responsive]="true" [editable]="true" [style]="{'margin-top':'50px'}">
                    <p-column field="labelName" header="Checklist" [style]="{'overflow':'visible', 'width':'300px'}"></p-column>
                    <p-column field="required" header="Required?" [editable]="true" [style]="{'overflow':'visible', 'width':'100px'}">
                        <ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [options]="RequiredValues" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></p-dropdown>
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-column>
                    <p-column field="received" header="Recived?" [editable]="true" [style]="{'overflow':'visible', 'width':'100px'}">
                        <ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                            <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" dataKey="label" [options]="RequiredValues" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" ></p-dropdown>
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-column>
                    <p-column field="receivedDate" header="Mail Received Date"></p-column>
                    <p-column field="mailReceivedDate" header="Mail Received Date"></p-column>
                    <p-column field="updatedBy" header="Updated By"></p-column>
                </p-dataTable>
```